# How to change/remove a month from <input type="date"

Tags: html, date, input

I'm trying to make a calendar where the month April can't be picked. Been searching around without luck.

(First question here, if there anything unclear just ask me and ill try too be more specific.) :)

Comment: i think javascript can do it

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
<input type="date" name="selectDate" id="selectDate" />
```

And

```
var selectDate = document.getElementById("selectDate");
selectDate.onchange = function(){
var d = document.getElementById("selectDate").value;
var dObject = new Date( d );
if (dObject.getMonth() + 1 == 4) {
    alert('You cant select month of April');
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5Lw2okp/32/) link here